# Как правильно сделать привязку к ширине окна в WPF С# используя MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Всем, привет! Возникла небольшая проблема, вдруг кто сталкивался.
Использую для написания программы WPF и паттерн MVVM, в процессе написания возникла необходимость привязаться к ширине окна разрабатываемой программы.

Во View за это отвечают следующие строки:

```
Title="Prog" Height="600"
Width="{ Binding Area_width, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" >
```

Во ViewModel за это отвечают следующие строки:

```
private string _Area_width;
public string Area_width
{
get { return _Area_width; }
set
{
_Area_width = value;
OnPropertyChanged();
}
}
```

Когда я разворачиваю окно на весь экран, Area_width принимает значение равное ширине экрана, но потом сразу меняется на старое значение, при этом окно развернуто. Когда размеры окна приложения редактируются мышкой(перетаскиванием границ) все работает нормально.

Задачка непростая, но вдруг кто сможет помочь. В любом случае спасибо!)

Comment: Все просто — развернутое (и свернутое) окно имеет специальное состояние, оно хранится в WindowState, просто отслеживайте ещё и это свойство

Comment: а почему не использовать разметку? xaml позволяет делать ширину или высоту контрола по размерам родителя вообще без кода и биндингов. Покажите вашу `xaml` разметку целиком и уточните задачу более буквально, пожалуйста.